# getTimestamp() does timezone converstion twice in MySQL JDBC connector?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a column of type `DATETIME` wiht a value of `2012-05-07 19:59:12` in MySQL database. I'm trying to retrieve this value from DB, assuming that it's stored in UTC timezone:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(new SimpleTimeZone(0, "UTC"));
Date date = resultSet.getTimestamp(1, cal);
System.out.println(date);
```

It outputs (`CEST` is my local timezone, which is 2 hours ahead of UTC):

```
Mon May 07 23:59:12 CEST 2012
```

Expected value is:

```
Mon May 07 21:59:12 CEST 2012
```

I'm using these three params in JDBC URL (`Europe/Berlin` is the same as `CEST`):

```
..&useGmtMillisForDatetimes=true&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=Europe/Berlin
```

Is it my defect or something should be configured additionally in the JDBC driver? I'm using `mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20`.

Comment: I think that you're making this a bit more complex than it needs to be. JDBC supports retrieving a timestamp with a calendar for when the database does not support timezones. MySQL does, so this is unnecessary. You can (probably) forget about all of the custom settings on the jdbc url too. Just use getDate(), and you will get a java.util.Date, which is timezone independent until you format it with a specific timezone.

Comment: Well, this is how it works: `&useGmtMillisForDatetimes=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC`, but thanks for your suggestion, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With these [JDBC URL params](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) it works:

```
useGmtMillisForDatetimes=true
useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true
useLegacyDate‌timeCode=false
useTimezone=true
serverTimezone=UTC
```

Comment: Great answer, worked perfectly for me.  Note: you have two (invisible) 0x00 characters between 'useLegacy' and 'DatetimeCode' which means this WONT work if someone copy-pastes it into a properties file.  I did this and it was awfully tough to track down.  Just in case anybody else tries this.

Comment: there were still invisible characters... now fixed!!

Comment: MySQL connector [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) says that properties `useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift` and `useTimezone` are mutually exclusive. I am successfully using `useTimezone=false`.

Comment: And useLegacyDate‌timeCode=false disables effect of useTimezone, useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift and useGmtMillisForDatetimes, so the only option needed is serverTimezone.

Comment: @RandyRizun Ha, ha. There is a `\u200c ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER`

Answer (score 0):

This is from documentation on [Connector/J 8.0.32 - Preserving Time Instants](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-time-instants.html) :

> Use `preserveInstants=true&connectionTimeZone=SERVER`
>
> This setting corresponds to the default behavior of Connector/J 8.0.22 and before and to the behavior of Connector/J 5.1 with `useLegacyDatetimeCode=false`.

I would suggest to follow that advice, remove `useTimezone=true` and `serverTimezone`, and then,

- for Connector/J 5.1 add `useLegacyDatetimeCode=false`,
- for 8.0.22 and before no additional change,
- for 8.0.23 add `preserveInstants=true` and `connectionTimeZone=SERVER`

so for your case with 5.1 (old posting), this would become

```
useLegacyDate‌timeCode=false
```

or for 8.0.23

```
preserveInstants=true
connectionTimeZone=SERVER
```

Also consider keeping your `useGmtMillisForDatetimes=true`, not sure why it was needed, but otherwise I have removed all other timezone related properties.