# How to set timezone to UTC in Play Framework 2.0 for both production and tests?

Tags: mysql, timezone, playframework-2.0

We'd like our Play Framework 2.0 Scala applications to handle all date and time information in UTC, both in the app servers and in MySQL database servers.

The trick is:

- Without changing deployment environment
- Without changing CI (testing) environment
- Without changing local (dev) environment

Is there a standard best practice to do this? We want the tests to run in UTC, without having to pass `-Duser.timezone=GMT` on all commandlines. Ditto for bringing up servers with `play start`.

Answer (score 8):

This was easier than we'd expected.

First, in `application.conf`, configure the JDBC URL with the parameters [as described on another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488529/gettimestamp-does-timezone-converstion-twice-in-mysql-jdbc-connector):

```
# Set MySQL Connector/J to use UTC server connection and time conversions
#   see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488529/gettimestamp-does-timezone-converstion-twice-in-mysql-jdbc-connector
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/database?useGmtMillisForDatetimes=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC"
```

Second, in `Build.scala`, set the Java system property and the default:

```
// Setting this property here forces the JVM to run in UTC time, 
// both for test (`play test`) and development (`play start`) modes, 
// but not for production (`play dist`).
System.setProperty("user.timezone", "GMT")
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))
```

These two changes together will handle both **test** (`play test`) and **development** (`play start`) modes.

For **production** (`play dist`), one must still set the property before launch. For example, by:

1. Editing the generated `start` script to add `export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Duser.timezone=GMT`
2. Invoking the `start` script with `-Duser.timezone=GMT`
3. Launching within an existing JVM after calling `System.setProperty("user.timezone", "GMT")`

Comment: Oops, original solution only worked for test (`play test`) and development (`play start`). Updated solution to support production (`play dist`) which does not run Build.scala

Comment: Inspired by this! FYI in our case, only needed two things: 1) `serverTimezone=UTC` in `slick.dbs.default.db.url` 2) config sbt run with `-Duser.timezone=UTC`